# TeraData REGEXP_REPLACE() Email Clean up

Tags: teradata

community! I am trying to get this syntax to work and I need some assistance. I need to remove everything after @ and capitalize the first initial and last intial of the name while removing any numbers at the end of the name. I am struggling to accomplish this. any rewrites would be appreciated.

Email:

1. LOGAN_SMITH@sample.email.com 
    caden_smith5@email.com 
   ANGELA_Smith1@my.email.com

Desired Outcome:

1. Logan Smith 
    Caden Smith 
    Angela Smith

```
,REGEXP_REPLACE(OREPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(EMAIL, '(^[^0-9@]+)', 1), '_', ' '),'(\w)(\w*)',X -> UPPER(X[1]) || LOWER(X[2])) FULL_NAME
```

Cheers~

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title provides no useful detail that can't be found in the tags (the single function name is not meaningful on its own). Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to be useful to a future site user who is scanning through a list of search results trying to find a solution to their problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a built-in function for capitalizing the first character of words:

```
InitCap(oTranslate(REGEXP_SUBSTR(EMAIL, '(^[^0-9@]+)', 1), '_', ' '))
```

Comment: @dnoeth.That worked perfectly! i didn't know about the InitaCap function. I learned something today. Thank you.